# Vanishing partial derivative of least squares w.r.t. Verhulst growth parameter

Tags: least-squares, gradient-descent, parameterization, growth-model

The Verhulst growth model can be given as

$$P(t) = \frac{k}{1+ \left( \frac{k-P_0}{P_0} \right)\exp(-rt)}$$

where $P(t)$ is the population size at time $t$, $k$ is the carrying capacity, $P_0$ is the initial population size, and $r$ is a rate parameter. We will consider all these values to be positive except for $r$ which may be any real number.

I am using a gradient-based method, so naturally I am considering the partial derivatives of the loss function with respect to the parameters. Given the least squares loss function, $\mathcal{L},$ the partial derivative of the loss with respect to the rate parameter $r$ is given by

$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial r} = - \frac{2 k t \left(k - p_{0}\right) \left(y- \frac{k}{1 + \frac{\left(k - p_{0}\right) e^{- r t}}{p_{0}}}\right) e^{- r t}}{p_{0} \left(1 + \frac{\left(k - p_{0}\right) e^{- r t}}{p_{0}}\right)^{2}}$$

where $y$ is some observed population size. Usually we would sum over the sample, but for simplicity of notation I am just considering what happens at a given point $(t,y)$.

The main problem at this point is that this partial derivative vanishes for even modest values of $t$

One could consider the log of the Verhulst growth, and ordinate data, however $\log (k-P_0)$ would assume that $k>P_0$, which I cannot assume. It is unclear if replacing $\log (k-P_0)$ with $\log |k-P_0|$.

How can I tweak this training setup to get best-fitting Verhulst parameters?

Comment: I don't follow "partial derivative vanishes for even modest values of $t,$" because the value of $r$ is just as critical here.  You should be analyzing what is going on for reasonable ranges of $rt,$ not just $t$ alone, because as $t$ grows, $P$ essentially stops varying with $t$ at all.

Comment: @whuber Indeed, and in the actual training iterations I am seeing the partial derivative for this one parameter vanish.

Comment: Perhaps simulated annealing, although slowly-converging, would be preferable over gradient descent since the step size decreases with the iteration number and is not a function of the gradient.

Comment: I am not optimistic about employing SA here.  If it works at all, then Newton-Raphson or even gradient descent are likely to work very well and quickly.  The problem is that the parameters are very difficult to identify unless you have a nice spread of observational times that include some early enough that $P(t)$ is still close to $P_0.$

Comment: @whuber Generally I share this lack of optimism for SA, but I have understated the problem. The derivative is not 'vanishing' in my training loop, but is rather already below numerical precision (i.e. zero). SA will allow updates of $r$ with $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial r} = 0$, but not any gradient-based method without increasing float precision. Either way, I need to rework my [class definition](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: @whuber Excellent point on the difficulty to identify parameters. I strongly agree.

Comment: Maybe you should be computing the logarithms of the absolute partial derivatives directly when $rt$ is large, thereby allowing you to (a) identify the terms that matter and (b) rescale them all before exponentiation so that you add them more precisely. You can still get in trouble with cancellation in $k-P_0,$ but that should be problematic only when almost all your observations are in the asymptotic regime, where you have no realistic hope of estimating $r$ anyway.

Comment: It would help to post a reproducible example of data that are causing you problems.